# Using UITableViewController logics in UITableViewDataSource class

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, refactoring

I'm doing a refactor because my `UITableViewController` is bloating very badly. The first thing I'm trying to do is refactoring the data source out of the table view controller like this:

```
// In my UITableViewController
let ds = MyDataSource()

func viewDidLoad() {
  tableView.dataSource = ds
}
```

In my data source class, I want to use some logic that I feel should belong in the table view controller.

```
class MyDataSource: UITableViewDataSource {
  func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // I want to use the variable showMore here
    return showMore ? 2 : 1
  }

  // More data source doe
}
```

The variable `showMore` is a boolean variable defined in my table view controller and is updated by a button in the footer view of a section.

Question is then, if `showMore` belongs in the table view controller, how can I access it from my data source class? If it doesn't belong in the 
table view controller, where does it belong and why?

Thanks!

Comment: Add the property showMore to both the VC and DS. Whenever it changes in the VC, pass it to the DS, and reload your table.  Or only keep it in the DS, when the user flicks the button, tell the DS to update the value and reload the table.

Answer (score 0):

First thought that comes to mind - and I'm just typing, not writing in Xcode...

```
// footerButtonTap
if let ds = tableView.dataSource as? MyDataSource {
    ds.showMore = !ds.showMore
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Or something along those lines might fit your needs.

Comment: And `showMore` can have a `didSet` attached to it which actually changes elements based on its value

Answer (score 0):

UITableViewController is Apple's convenient implementation of a UIViewController that contains a tableView instead of a view, as well as conforming immediately to `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate`. I'd recommend you just use a `UIViewController` and add a tableView, and then proceed as you have by setting the table's delegate and datasource to `MyCustomTableController`, which would conform to both `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate`. All logic should be handled inside the controller.

Comment: Understood, but my table view controller is bloating to +1000 lines.. It's getting extremely hard to maintain and add feature/debug, hence the question.

Comment: Yes, this is why I recommended you split your hefty table view controller up.